# Cant pass data from one method to another in same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing MVC application.

I am trying to pass the data from one method to another method in same controller.

But data doesn't pass properly...

Please check below code... I am trying to pass the Product list from  Create to Save data method.

```
namespace StockWatchScreen.Controllers
{
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        public class OrderProduct
        {
            public string SectionCode { get; set; }
            public double Size { get; set; }
            public double Thickness { get; set; }
            public double Length { get; set; }
            public double Quantity { get; set; }   
        }

         public ActionResult Create()
         {
             List<OrderProduct> oProductList = new List<OrderProduct>();

             OrderProduct oProduct = new OrderProduct();
             oProduct.SectionCode = "123";
             oProduct.Length = "123";
             oProduct.Size = "123";
             oProduct.Thickness =  "123";
             oProduct.Quantity = "123";
             oProductList.Add(oProduct);     
            }    

          return RedirectToAction("SaveData", oProductList);           
       }

        public ActionResult SaveData(List<OrderProduct> oProductList)
        {
            ViewBag.ProductList = oProductList;
            ViewBag.OrderNo = "12321#";
            return View();
        }

        }
    }
}
```

In SaveData method, oProductList list shows always null.

What is reason ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return :`return SaveData( oProductList);`  .You don't need to return RedirectToAction , and try to avoid using `TempData["oProduct"]` using TempData in mvc is not good practice. 
Using AjaxBeginForm you on succes you can get result  `return SaveData( oProductList);`and put it where you want .also you can use UpdateTargetId.

Comment: I'm not sure if this work, you can't call a action result like a method in MVC, Also temp data can be handy in many situations and as it is a temporary allocation of session data it is not a bad practise like Session.

Comment: Why you can not call ActionResult like a method?

Comment: Please try doing that, If I'm correct here it will return 'Create' view itself or some error.

Comment: Please try to be more detailed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't send model like this in `RedirectToAction`, you should use `tempdata` for this communicating between actions like this

```
      public ActionResult Create()
      {
             List<OrderProduct> oProductList = new List<OrderProduct>();
             OrderProduct oProduct = new OrderProduct();
             oProduct.SectionCode = "123";
             oProduct.Length = "123";
             oProduct.Size = "123";
             oProduct.Thickness =  "123";
             oProduct.Quantity = "123";
             oProductList.Add(oProduct);
           }

         TempData["oProduct"] = oProductList; 
         return RedirectToAction("SaveData");
        }
```

And in the recieving controller

```
    public ActionResult SaveData(List<OrderProduct> oProductList)
    {
        ViewBag.ProductList = TempData["oProduct"] as List<OrderProduct> ;
        ViewBag.OrderNo = "12321#";
        return View();
    }
```

This is because `RedirectToAction` is doing a `301` redirection, and it is actually the client initiating a `Get` request to the `/SaveData` action.

Comment: This works... Thanks...  but Im still not getting why its showing null ?  In other controller, I have use the same function its working ok, the difference is, I use single object there and I am using list of object here...

Comment: @user1650894 I was wondering which answer really worked for you. Does the first answer you accepted really working for you.